# can a transparent object hide a specific object behind it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I have a problem. Can I make a moving object x be hidden behind a transparent plane y so, that every other object behind plane y is visible?
Thank You in advance[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Input* > *Light Path* node, *Transparent Depth* output, used as a factor in a *Mix* shader, seems to work:

[image]

Comment: omg thank you agaaaaain <3 it works

Answer (score 4):

This is is specifically what the **Holdout Shader** is for

The **Cube** in front has the **Holdout Shader Material** and the **Cube** behind is a **Diffuse Shader** set to Green.

[image]

Note: the **Shadow** from the front **Cube** is preserved.

[image]

Comment: interesting, but it erase all the objects behind though... for the shadow, it can be removed in Object > Cycles Settings > Shadow